# passing multiline string variable from c# to javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

I have a webpage that checks login credentials. The page calls a function which then makes a connection to a table in a oracle database and checks to see that this user is allow to see the application. This is all done using c# however if their is a fatal error from the database, i would like to notify the user using javascript. in my c# code i have a string variable that will basically print the javascript function into the webpage. it looks like this.

```
                    string javaScript =
                    "<script>"+
                    "var find = ':';"+
                    "var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');" +
                    "str='@"+CheckAccess[0]._ERROR.ToString().Replace(":"," ")+"';"+
                    "str = str.replace(re, '');"+
                    "if ($('#login_error').css('display') == 'none') {" +

                    "$('#login_error').text(str).show(); }" +
                    "else {Return;}</script>";
```

When the database return an error it return a multiline error the looks like this.

```
  ORA-06550 line 1, column 7
PLS-00306 wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GETUSERACCESS'
ORA-06550 line 1, column 7
PL/SQL Statement ignored at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck)
```

All the examples Ive seen on the web say to break  it up with "/" so that i dont continue to get the  "unterminated string literal" error. However i don't see an efficient way to do this. Could there be a better way to achieve what I'm trying to accomplish or do i have to some how figured out a way to parse this string and guess where the line breaks are going to be. Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks 
Miguel

Comment: Why not put this logic in your JS code and pass a bit from the C# to determine what behavior to take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to "guess" where the line breaks will be. The are usually represented by one or two special escape characters:

- `\r` (CR = carriage return), and
- `\n` (NL = new line).

(MS Windows usually use CRLF, Unix-based systems have traditionally used only LF, but this may vary). For example, you can find them with `CheckAccess[0]._ERROR.ToString().IndexOf("\r\n")`, and use the same technique to replace them.

Since you know you will be pushing error text directly to HTML element, you can replace the `\r\n` (CRLF) with `<br/>` (HTML line break).

Code:

`CheckAccess[0]._ERROR.ToString().Replace(":"," ").Replace("\r\n", "<br/>")`

Since Oracle can run on Unix machines also (for example) and may return just LF in the error message instead of CRLF you may want to be extra safe and be generic, first try to replace CRLF, then CR, then LF:

`CheckAccess[0]._ERROR.ToString().Replace(":"," ")
    .Replace("\r\n", "<br/>")
    .Replace("\r", "<br/>")
    .Replace("\n", "<br/>")`

Then your javascript will not inject the whitespace from the CRLF, and will instead render the html to create the line breaks.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the response. this is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend trying to do it the way you are right now. Something smells about having JS code written out in a C# string like that, e.g. it looks like it'd be possible for an injection attack to occur, if the error message string doesn't include what you expected it to.

Instead of trying to pass JS code to the client when an error occurs, you could include the JS code to handle errors in the page to start with, then just pass a JSON-serialized data structure containing your error string. That should allow multiline strings and other special characters to pass from the server to the client correctly.

E.g. if your class is something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Then your controller method might look like:

```
public JsonResult TryToValidate(...)
{
    MyClass myClass = // result
    return Json(myClass);
}
```

With pseudo-JS on the login page that looks like:

```
MakeAjaxCallToTryToValidate(...)
.whenThatsDone(function ...() {
    if !result.Success
        alert(result.ErrorMessage);
});
```

Or, since you shouldn't really be exposing error details to average users anyway, you could just log the error's details on the server where the admin can see it, and give the user a generic error message. If it was something invalid that you might expect the user to do, (e.g. type in a wrong password) then the error message should tell them so, and how to fix it themselves, but a "wrong number or types of arguments" error isn't usually in that category.

Comment: This method would be my preference. Besides your point about injection, it is also dangerous to naively render messages like this because it may expose vital implementation details to potential attackers, like table names, column names - and the fact the DB is Oracle, knowing which narrows the attacker's toolset greatly...